# discord.js v13 is there a way to add choices in slash command numbers option?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a slash command with a number option. I'm using `.addNumberOption()` for this.

Is there a way to make it only possible to submit numbers between 0-5 after typing the discord command?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`setMinValue()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/builders/main/class/SlashCommandNumberOption?scrollTo=setMinValue) and [`setMaxValue()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/builders/main/class/SlashCommandNumberOption?scrollTo=setMaxValue) to set minimum and maximum values. If you type anything out of that range as the option, you'll receive an error message:

[image]

```js
new SlashCommandBuilder()
  .setName('numberchoice')
  .setDescription('Just some test')
  .addNumberOption((option) =>
    option
      .setName('num')
      .setDescription('Type a number between 0 and 5')
      .setMinValue(0)
      .setMaxValue(5)
  )
```

PS: Are you sure you want to accept numbers and not only integers? If the latter, use the `addIntegerOption` instead.

Comment: TypeError: option.setName(...).setDescription(...).setMinValue is not a function you know why

Comment: What's your discord.js version? You can check it in your `package.json` file.